# Refresh Datatable on Insert Item

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm a newbie.

I am using ngx-datatable.

Is there a way to refresh the UI View of the ngx-datatable.

Like rerender everything

Please see screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Thanks,

pOng

Comment: You should share code to see where the problem is

Comment: @ping pong please share code in stackblitz

Comment: i found the issue and it seems to be fix.
  @ViewChild(DatatableComponent, { static: false }) table: DatatableComponent;

Answer (score 1):

the fix on my issue is

@ViewChild(DatatableComponent, { static: false }) table: DatatableComponent;
 this.table.recalculate()

also please refer to this link
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1733